# How to compute $\sum^{n}_{i=0}(2t)^i$

Tags: calculus

How can I work out this easy sum?

$$\sum^{n}_{i=0}(2t)^i$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This is the sum of the first $n+1$ terms of a geometric series. [Use the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).